# Dependency injection with CFFI?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, python-cffi

I'm trying to make a toy/proof-of-concept [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/)-based Python library exposing the [PQClean](https://github.com/pqclean/PQClean) implementation of [Classic McEliece](https://classic.mceliece.org/) KEM version 6960119f.

The documentation notes that you must "Provide instantiations of any of the common cryptographic algorithms used by the implementation". This is true, because this code:

```py
from cffi import FFI
ffibuilder = FFI()

ffibuilder.cdef("""
int PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_enc(
    uint8_t *c,
    uint8_t *key,
    const uint8_t *pk
);

int PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_dec(
    uint8_t *key,
    const uint8_t *c,
    const uint8_t *sk
);

int PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_keypair
(
    uint8_t *pk,
    uint8_t *sk
);
""")

ffibuilder.set_source("_libmceliece6960119f", """
  #include "api.h"
""",
    library_dirs=["Lib/PQClean/crypto_kem/mceliece6960119f/clean"],
    include_dirs=["Lib/PQClean/crypto_kem/mceliece6960119f/clean"],
    libraries=["libmceliece6960119f_clean"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    assert 'x64' == os.environ['VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH'] == os.environ['VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH']
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
    #^ Code crashes here
    from _libmceliece6960119f import lib as libmceliece6960119f
    ...
```

yields MSVC error 1120 due to lacking implementations for `void shake256(uint8_t *output, size_t outlen, const uint8_t *input, size_t inlen);` and `int randombytes(uint8_t *output, size_t n);`:

```
   Creating library .\Release\_libmceliece6960119f.cp311-win_amd64.lib and object .\Release\_libmceliece6960119f.cp311-win_amd64.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
libmceliece6960119f_clean.lib(operations.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol shake256
libmceliece6960119f_clean.lib(operations.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PQCLEAN_randombytes
libmceliece6960119f_clean.lib(encrypt.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PQCLEAN_randombytes
.\_libmceliece6960119f.cp311-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\████\Documents\code\███\cffi_compile.py", line 34, in <module>
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
  File "C:\Users\████\.venvs\███\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 725, in compile
    return recompile(self, module_name, source, tmpdir=tmpdir,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\████\.venvs\███\Lib\site-packages\cffi\recompiler.py", line 1564, in recompile
    outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile('.', ext,
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\████\.venvs\███\Lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 20, in compile
    outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose, debug)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\████\.venvs\███\Lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 54, in _build
    raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
cffi.VerificationError: LinkError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
```

I **don't** want to choose an implementation for either of these functions at compile-time. I want to [force the consumer of this library to provide one early in run-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), ideally as Python functions `Callable[[bytes], bytes], Callable[[int], bytes]` (neither function needs to implement any streaming capabilities because the `shake256_inc_…` suite apparently isn't required by the `PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_crypto_kem_…` suite.)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by providing a C implementation that calls back to Python code, but write that Python code in such a way as to allow being overridden.

This should be enough:

```
ffibuilder.cdef("""
   ...same stuff as before...
   extern "Python+C" void shake256(uint8_t *output, size_t outlen, const uint8_t *input, size_t inlen);
   extern "Python+C" int randombytes(uint8_t *output, size_t n);
""")
```

It causes the two functions to be emitted as C code, where the compiler should find them.  But the two functions are written so that they call back Python code.  At runtime, that Python code must provide two global functions:

```
@ffi.def_extern()
def shake256(output_ptr, outlen, input_ptr, inlen):
    xxx
@ffi.def_extern()
def randombytes(output_ptr, n):
    xxx
```

which you can implement as you see fit.  For example, in your library's Python code, you can write something like that:

```
def register_randombytes(fn):
    """Call this global function from the code using this library.
         fn(number_of_bytes) -> bytes
    """
    global _my_randombytes
    _my_randombytes = fn

@ffi.def_extern()
def randombytes(output_ptr, n):
    rbytes = _my_randombytes(n)
    if len(rbytes) > n:
        raise ValueError("User randombytes function returned too much data!")
    ffi.memmove(output_ptr, rbytes, len(rbytes))
    return len(rbytes)
```

It's not a very flexible API because the user needs to give a single, global function.  Multiple users overwrite each other.  But it's hard to do better because the C API doesn't provide a generic `void *data` parameter to the callbacks.